# Adding Parameters after creating an object OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

**REVISED**

I have a simple question, but being new to OOP I am not sure if this is possible.

Currently I have a class with one function that accepts an argument.
What the actual function does is irrelevant.

```
<?php
class Method {

    public function show($parameter){
        echo $parameter;
    }

}
?>
```

I create the object like this...

```
$this->Method = new Method();
```

And use it like this...

```
$this->Method->show($parameter);
```

So the question is, can my function be set up in a way to simplify the use to
this...

```
$this->Method($parameter);
```

I tried by changing the function to a `__construct` and using the above line of code but it fails since the `new Method()` was created without a `$parameter` specified.

I was hoping to be able to pass the `$parameter` after the `new Method();` was called.

Comment: What would `$this->Method($parameter);` do in this example?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Well...nothing...that's my issue, haha

Comment: Well, it potentially _can_ do something, but I'm just not certain what you had in mind. If you want it to be callable, you can give it an `__invoke` method, but I don't know if that's what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. If you add an `__invoke()` method to your class, instances of that class can be called like you would a method.

```
class Method {
    public function __invoke($param) {
        echo $param;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your class the way you want to

```
$this->Method = new Method;
$this->Method('something');  // echos something
```

If you still want to have the `show` method (or whatever the method actually is) as well, you can leave it there and just call it in `__invoke` instead.

```
class Method {
    public function show($param) {
        echo $param;
    }
    public function __invoke($param) {
        $this->show($param);
    }
}
```

---

Another possibility, because it looks like you are wanting to be able to use an object like you would use a function, is to define a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and use it in the object that currently has a `Method` instead of using a `Method` class. If you create a trait like:

```
trait CanUseMethod {
    public function Method ($parameter) {
        echo $parameter;
    }
}
```

Then in the class that needs to use `Method`, instead of

```
$this->Method = new Method;
```

You can use the trait like this:

```
class Example {
    use CanUseMethod;
}
```

Then your `Example` class will be able to use `Method` without creating a new object.

Comment: Great! I had a feeling there was a magic method I could use. I kept trying within `__construct` with no luck. Thank you again!